# Excel Return Row and Column Headers of Nonzero Values in Table VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table with a bunch of zeros and values. I'd like to write a code that goes through each cell within the table, and when a cell has a nonzero value, the macro would list the row and column names of each nonzero cell.

```
             Kroger Meijer Wholefoods Walmart     
Food           0      0       0         1         Food, Walmart
Electronics    0      1       0         1         Electronics, Meijer; Electronics Walmart
Gas            0      0       1         0         Gas, Wholefoods
Crafts         0      1       0         0         Crafts, Meijer
```

In terms of code, I don't really know how to accomplish this beyond selecting all the nonzero cells.

```
Sheets("NA_CM1").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("ItI_COMPLETE_NACM1").Range.Select
For Each cell In Range("ItI_COMPLETE_NACM1")
If cell.Value <> 0 Then
    If my_range Is Nothing Then
        Set my_range = cell
    Else
        Set my_range = Union(my_range, cell)
        End If
End If
```

Comment: End it with `debug.print my_range.address(0,0)`. btw, you could likely cut down your loop by looking through `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)` instead of every cell.

Answer (score 1):

A possible Non-VBA solution would involve using a [Reverse Pivot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pUXJLzqlEPk) to flatten your cross-tab data, then filtering on where Value > 0. Then you will have all Items in each Store that are > 0 in amount.

End Result is like this:

[image]

For a VBA solution, give this a shot. It copies to column K of each row, based on your example table.

```
Sheets("NA_CM1").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("ItI_COMPLETE_NACM1").Range.Select

For Each cell In Range("ItI_COMPLETE_NACM1")

    If cell.Value <> 0 Then

        Dim sValue As String
        sValue = Cells(cell.Row, 11).Value2

        If Len(sValue) = 0 Then

            Cells(cell.Row, 11).Value = Cells(cell.Row, 1).Value2 & "," & Cells(1, cell.Column).Value2

        Else

            Cells(cell.Row, 11).Value = sValue & "; " & Cells(cell.Row, 1).Value2 & "," & Cells(1, cell.Column).Value2

        End If

    End If

Next
```

Comment: Does this code populate to only one specific column

Comment: @MikeGiedzinski yes, sorry, I set it to copy to col K and forgot to mention that. You can change it by changing `Cells(cell.Row,11)` to whatever column number you like. Or let me know if you want concurrent columns.

Answer (score 0):

A different solution (to give you a choice) :)

```
Sub testing()
  Dim cVal As Variant, oVal() As Variant, i As Long, j As Long
  cVal = Sheets("NA_CM1").Range("ItI_COMPLETE_NACM1").Value
  ReDim oVal(1 To UBound(cVal), 1 To 1)
  oVal(1, 1) = cVal(1, UBound(cVal, 2))
  For i = 2 To UBound(cVal)
    oVal(i, 1) = cVal(i, 1) & ", "
    For j = 2 To UBound(cVal, 2) - 1
      If cVal(i, j) <> 0 Then
        oVal(i, 1) = oVal(i, 1) & cVal(1, j) & "; "
      End If
    Next
    oVal(i, 1) = Left(oVal(i, 1), Len(oVal(i, 1)) - 2)
  Next
  Sheets("NA_CM1").Range("ItI_COMPLETE_NACM1").Columns(UBound(cVal, 2)) = oVal
End Sub
```

it asumes your first example is the whole table (row 1 = headers; col 1 = headers; last col = output). so the `Sheets("NA_CM1").Range("ItI_COMPLETE_NACM1").Columns(UBound(cVal, 2)) = oVal` prints the output as one col over the last col of your table (but you can put `oVal` anywhere you want)... should also be pretty fast when doing it for big tables (also works if there more or less than 4 columns to look at)... i just checks the second to the second last col...